# Correct date format using VBA to import XML

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently working on a spreadsheet for analysing data exported from the online t-card system we use. This exports all of its data in XML format.
To import this data I use a macro to save it all to another worksheet and convert most of the columns to values, as they are all stored as text. However the problem I'm having is converting the text in the date columns to actual dates. I'm using this code to convert to dates:

```
With ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns("U").Cells
.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
.Value = .Value
End With
```

While this works for some dates where the day is greater than 12, for others where it is 12 or less, it is using the day as the month and vice versa.

For example, when using the following XML entry:

```
<TCard>
      <Ref>*****</Ref>
      <CUSTOMER_NAME>*****</CUSTOMER_NAME>
      <ORDER_NUMBER>*****</ORDER_NUMBER>
      <ACCOUNT_NUMBER>*****</ACCOUNT_NUMBER>
      <ITEM_NUMBER_DELIVERY_AREA>*****</ITEM_NUMBER_DELIVERY_AREA>
      <Description>PFC 230 X 90 / 5 @ 12.2</Description>
      <Colour>Stock Bar PP</Colour>
      <SlotPosition>35</SlotPosition>
      <RowTitle></RowTitle>
      <AssignedDate>20/02/2017</AssignedDate>
      <EndDate />
      <AssignedColumnTitle>Monday</AssignedColumnTitle>
      <Locked>False</Locked>
      <Order_Date>17/02/2017</Order_Date>
      <Due_Date>21/02/2017</Due_Date>
      <Weight_kg>1972</Weight_kg>
      <DrillSaw_Time>-</DrillSaw_Time>
      <Blaster_Time>-</Blaster_Time>
      <Saw_Time>-</Saw_Time>
    </TCard>
```

When the macro runs it will give the assigned date as 20/02/2017 for this entry, which is correct, however on another where the assigned date is 08/03/2017 (8th March 2017), the macro changes this to 03/08/2017 (3rd August 2017).

Unfortunately I don't think other methods that suggest using trimmed inputs will work as dates over the 12th of each month are correct.

Is there a way for the macro to change the date stored as text to DD/MM/YYYY format only from the XML?

Apologies in advance if there is something glaringly obvious that I am missing, I've only learned basic VBA nessacery for this project

Comment: Hi Harry, instead of converting the data to a date after you have written it to the sheet, why don't you write it to the sheet as a date? Have a look at the [DateValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6d6k22a5(v=vs.90).aspx) function, if you look at the remarks section I think you'll find the culprit of the behavior you're experiencing

Comment: Yes, but it needs to be done **before** the value is written to a worksheet cell, or else you need to change your windows regional settings to match the date format in the xml document.  That date format, by the way, is non-standard for xml.  Maybe it has changed, but the last I looked the recommended date format was `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss` with an optional timezone token.

Comment: DateValue is exactly what I needed, thank you. I'm currently creating new columns for the dates, using these instead. As the imported data is stored on another sheet, it doesn't matter too much if it's messy. As for the regional settings, both me and tcard system we use are based within the UK so that hasn't been an issue, but thanks for pointing that out.